# Filter Adapter with SearchView - Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to filter my adapter. I have a recyclerView which sets up this adapter. I am stack with how to filter the my adapter. i don't seem to have the keyword `filter` for my adapter. With the tutorial i am following, it filters the adapter in this format `adapter.filter.InvokeFilter` but i get 
an error doing that.

What am i missing out?

**PS** I have already set up my adapter and it displays data using recyclerView

**Activity**

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {

            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.top_menus, menu);

            var item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.search);

            var searchview = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView)MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(item);

            searchview.SetOnQueryTextListener(this);

            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }


public bool OnQueryTextChange(string newText)
        {
           //this is where i get the error
           adapter.filter
        }

        public bool OnQueryTextSubmit(string query)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class CountryAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        private JavaList<Country> country;
        private Context context;
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
        public CountryActivity nation;



        public CountryAdapter(JavaList<Country> country, Context context)
        {
            this.country =country;
            this.context = context;
            nation = (CountryActivity)context;

        }




        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            CountryHolder hold = holder as CountryHolder;

         }  

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.List_Item, parent, false);
            CountryHolder holder = new CountryHolder (v, OnClick,nation);

            return holder;       
        }

        public override int ItemCount {

            get {return nation.Size(); }

        } 


        void OnClick(int position)
        {
            if (ItemClick != null)
                ItemClick(this, position);
        }

       }
```

Comment: Probably he was filtering `ListView`

Comment: This tutorial help me a lot, maybe can help you too

https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

Comment: @Yupi, Yeah i just checked and he  was working on ListView. Is there anyway for recyclerView?

Comment: @LearnXamarin for `RecyclerView` you have to make custom adapter and you probably did that if your `RecyclerView` is working. Can you update code with your adapter code?

Comment: @Yupi i have updated the code with my adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure will this work but I hope it will help you. Try to create a method inside your adapter class like:

```
public void Filter(JavaList<Country> countries)
{
    country = new JavaList<>();
    country.addAll(countries);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then in your `Activity` where are you trying to preform searching:

```
public bool OnQueryTextChange(string newText)
    {
       newText = newText.ToLowerCase();
       JavaList<Country> countriesList = new JavaList<>();
       foreach(Country country : countries) // data which you used for populating adapter
        {
           String name = country.getName.ToLowerCase(); // I don't know how your Country class code is setup I suppose you have getters and setters like name for countries
        if(name.Contains(newText))
            countriesList.add(country );
        }
    countyadapter.Filter(countriesList);
    return true;
    }
```